# How to merge selected features with different attributes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, features, expression

I want to merge several features with attribute values that fall within a certain range. I use Select by Expression to select the relevant features, but when I click merge selected features, QGIS times out and ends up crashing. I think it's because the features have many attributes, which are different, and QGIS is not sure how to merge them. I thought I would be prompted with a window to define the attributes after the merge, but I guess not?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using? I suggest you to create an issue here: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try the ***Dissolve*** algorithm (under *Vector geometry* in the *Processing toolbox*).

When you have selected the features to be merged, you can merge them using ***Dissolve*** (with *Selected features only*, and no *Dissolve field(s)* specified).
The resulting layer will only contain the generated (multi) feature.